# Equalize array by subtracting values from indexes

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling with this particular problem and am not very sure how to approach it, any idea would really be appreciated.

I have an array of size n, for example, 3

```
[8, 10, 5]
```

I want to subtract values from this array until all the indexes become equal, using the smallest amount of subtracted values as possible.
The answer for this particular question would be

```
8 10 5
8 8 3       Subtract 2 from index 1 and 2
3 3 3       Subtract 5 from index 0 and 1
[3, 3, 3]
```

Requirements:
Array must not move (no moving indexes)
Only subtracting is allowed
You are only allowed to subtract by TWO indexes that are right NEXT to each other (eg. if I want to decrease index[1], I would have to also decrease index[0] or index[2]) 
Subtracting multiple indexes must be the same value (eg. subtracting index[1] by 3, I must choose an index right next to index[1] and subtract that by the same amount (3))

Objective: Make all values in the array equal by subtracting as less as possible.

Any help is appreciated, as I have absolutely no idea of how to even start tackling this!

Comment: How is the answer `{3, 3, 3}`. What are the steps you took to get that answer?

Comment: The array indexes are 0, 1, 2.  They do not change.  I think you mean that the **elements** become equal.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated my question.

Comment: There are many input arrays for which this is simply not possible. Are there any extra constraints?

Comment: Is the array limited to 3 elements? In your question you state size n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you find the maximum and the minimum by iterating the array .
for eg, in this

```
array = {8,10,5}
```

max is 10 and min is 5.

Then you subtract the difference  (5) from the maximum and its adjacent and ignoring the value which is in less adjacent.( in this case, neighbours of 10 are 8,5 -> therefore, subtract 5 from 8) ,then

```
   arrays ={3,5,5}
```

now again iterate the array and find max and min ( 5,3)
. Subtract the difference ( 5-3 =2 ) from the max and its adjcent neighbour with more value ( from 3,5  , subtract 2 from 5 )
then your array becomes

```
  arrays ={3,3,3}
```

Comment: If I may ask, what would you do for ```[4,6,4,4,6,4]``` because the smallest is ```[2,2,2,2,2,2]```

Comment: So I think you can do like 
```[4 6 4 4 6 4]
[2 4 4 4 6 4]
[2 2 2 4 6 4]
[2 2 2 2 4 4]
[2 2 2 2 2 2]
 ```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution :

```
static int equalizeArray(int N, int k, int arr[])
{

   long   steps=0;
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   int mid=0;
   if(N%2==1){
       mid=N/2;
   }
   else{
       mid=N/2-1;
   }
   for( int i=0;i<N;i++){

       if(  (Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[mid]))%k!=0){
           return -1;
       }
   }
   for( int i=0;i<N;i++){
   long   diff=Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[mid]);
       steps+=(diff/k)%1000000007;
   }
   return (int)steps%1000000007;
   
}
```

Comment: best case complexity : O(n) Worst case complexity: O n long n